# Show name instead of ID in has_many view table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have tried a couple other similar posts but am still getting an error.

In the Posts model I have a category_id field.  I have the following models:

```
#Posts model
belongs_to :categories  

#Category model
has_many :posts
```

In the Posts index controller I have:

```
@categories = @posts.Category.find(:all, :order => 'categoryname')
```

In the View I have:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<tr>
<td><%= post.category_id %></td>
<td><%= @categories.categoryname %></td>

<td><%= link_to 'View', post %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

In the 2nd column I am trying to show the category name ("categoryname") from the Category table instead of the category_id from the posts table.  I am getting an error:

undefined method `Category' for #ActiveRecord::Relation:0x3e1a9b0>

I have also tried:

```
<td><%= post.categories.categoryname %></td>
```

But get the same error.

As well as:

```
<td><%= post.category.categoryname %></td>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your model

```
belongs_to :category
```

In your view

```
<td><%= post.category.categoryname %></td>
```

You can get rid of the `@categories =` line in your controller

Also, categoryname is probably not the best attribute name for your Category model. Why not just name it `name`. `post.category.name` seems a lot better than `post.category.categoryname`, don't you think?

Comment: I have made the change to the model and the view.  I am now getting: undefined method `categoryname' for nil:NilClass on the line:  <td><%= post.category.categoryname %></td>   I do agree .name would be better than categoryname, I will change that once I get this to work first.

Comment: Ah, I see what happened.  I had a null value in one, that is why it threw the error.  I removed it and it is showing the names!!!  Thank you xnm and DVG!!

Answer (score 4):

Okay, a couple things

```
belongs_to :categories
```

belongs_to is a singular relationship. You should be putting

```
belongs_to :category
```

In this case you need category_id in the posts table. You would get the category by

```
@post.category.categoryname
```

Unless a post can have many categories, in which case you'd want

```
#Post
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

#Category
has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
```

In this case you need a join table called `categories_posts` with two fields `category_id` and `post_id` and you would get it by calling

```
@post.categories.each do |cat|
  cat.categoryname
end
```

There are some other problems with you code, like

```
@categories = @posts.Category.find(:all, :order => 'categoryname')
```

Category is a model, not your named relationship, which is probably why you are getting the exception in your application.

Answer (score 2):

You will get the following error

> > undefined method `categoryname' for nil:NilClass on the line: <%= post.category.categoryname %>

if there are records in your table without a category specified.

In other words, make sure all of your records have a category associated with them

Answer (score 0):

i Noticed that @category in your controller starts with a small letter c, but in your view, it starts with a Capital letter !

Answer (score 0):

In your case, if there is a chance that you can have an empty category_id in posts table *(as you mentioned in your comment)*, you can add

```
if post.category_id?
```

so your cell will look like this:

```
<td><%= post.category.categoryname if post.category_id? %></td>
```

If post.category_id is null it will just show an empty cell.