# Rails 4: Get customer names from orders data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model

I have 2 models, Order and Customer:

```
  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "customer_id", limit: 4
    t.decimal  "subtotal",                precision: 10
    t.decimal  "tax",                     precision: 10
    t.decimal  "total",                   precision: 10
    t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
  end

  create_table "customers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",       limit: 255
    t.string   "email",      limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
  end
```

And I'm listing all the orders but want to include the customer name on the html table, not the customer id.

My Orders controller index method is:

```
def index
  @orders = Order.all.order('id DESC')
end
```

How I can include the customer name on the index method for each order?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show name instead of ID in has\_many view table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762669/show-name-instead-of-id-in-has-many-view-table)

Comment: how about `@orders = Order.includes(:customer)`

Comment: Awesome, very simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to setup a [relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) between your Customer and Order classes. As you have added a `customer_id` column to you Order table, I can assume that a Customer can have many Orders or, in other terms, there may be many different orders that may have been made by the same customer(unless you want to restrict). So, you add the `has_many` association to the Customer model.

**Customer.rb:**

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```

Subsequently, an Order belongs to a customer, so we add the corresponding, `belongs_to` association.

**Order.rb:**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

Add the following cell in your **HTML table:**

```
<td><%= order.customer.name %></td>
```